# Update rows limit in Snowflake

Tags: sql, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I there a way to update values for top-n/limit amount of records in Snowflake?

Sample data, top rows are the ones that need to flaged:

[image]

The logic must combine `SELECT n FROM limit 200` with `SET FLAG = 1`

Below syntax is not working:

```
--option 1
UPDATE TBL_NAME limit 20000
       SET FLAG = 1
--option 2
WITH CTE as (SELECT * FROM TBL_NAME LIMIT 20000)
UPDATE CTE
       SET FLAG = '1'
```

Comment: Please add the table structure and logic to calculate the top n rows

Comment: Does your table have a key?  If so, you could select a limited number of records using a CTE, and then join that back to the original table on the key in an update statement.  Question is, why would you want to randomly update a subset of data?  Is there an ORDER BY that you'd be using?

Comment: Snowflake does not enforce keys Mike.

Comment: @marcin2x4 I wasn't asking for constraints, I was asking if the data had a unique, natural key that can be used to identify the records.  I'm aware that primary keys are not enforced.

Comment: @Mike Walton - ok, there is a natural key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to update only a limited number of rows, you can try this with `seq8()`:

```sql
create or replace temp table many_a 
as 
select 'aaaaaaa' str
from table(generator(rowcount => 100));

update many_a
set str='b'
where seq8()<5
```

[image]

[image]

Note: if you're doing this over large amounts of data, `seq8()` might behave in unexpected ways. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/seq1.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the existence of a natural key, you could simply join from a sub-query like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_name t
SET flag = 1
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM tbl_name
  LIMIT 20000
  ) x
WHERE t.natural_key = x.natural_key;
```